# Is Azure's B-2 app service plan better than a S-1 for production environments?

Tags: azure

When using Azure's WebApps to run C# MVC based applications on production environments, I'm always wondering about when to use the B-2 (Basic-2 with 2-cores and 3.5 GB) and when to use S-1 (Standard-1 with 1-core and 1.75GB).

It sure sounds like the B-2 would result in better performance, still all official recommendations for production use is to run it on S-1 or above. Maybe there's some CPU throttling on B-* plans? Or other 'bottle-neck' that I'm not aware?

Or should I be better off just using the B-2 for production (over a S-1)?

Answer (score 2):

The B-series has this name from *burstable* adjective.

It means that you do not have 100% of the cores for 100% of the time (see [Introducing B-Series, our new burstable VM size](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-b-series-our-new-burstable-vm-size/)).
For example B-2 you have guaranteed only 40% out of a potential 200%.

The suggestion to pick a different serie for production workload, is to guarantee the CPU available.

Comment: Ok, got it. But since the S-1 app plan still uses B-Series for processing, I'm assuming that I can safely ignore their 'suggestion' to use S-* app plans instead of B-* for productions. Right?

Comment: @marcelo-myara I thought the S* plans used A-series VMs behind the scenes?